# Find the Tangent line that intersects the graph at another point

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vectors, roots, cubics

I am having trouble figuring out methodology to find another point of intersection for my tangent line $y=-38x+6$ and curve $2x^3+10x^2-28x$.

The question asks to determine tangent line at $x=-3$ for above function, and I know that they already intersect at $(-3, 120)$ having solved for $f(a)$. and using the secant method to find the slope of the above tangent line at $x=-3$.

Find another point of intersection:
$-38x+6 = 2x^3+10x^2-28x$
$0=2x^3+10x^2+10x-6$ [solve for roots]

I know that $(x+3)$ is a root by method of substitution for figuring $zero$ of the $cubic$, and when I perform the long div I end up with a remainder. It makes me think my methodology is incorrect. 
How should I solve this one? Thanks

Comment: Try the long division again -- you made an error in it at some point.  In fact, if you instead divide by $(x+3)^2$ it'll give the answer quicker.

Comment: @BrianMoehring thanks - I indeed made an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$2x^3+10x^2+10x-6=2 (x+3) \left(x^2+2 x-1\right)$$

Comment: Thanks! I factored out the $2$ in the quadratic and employed quadratic formula to success.